# How can I make count() as a condition when I update a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(TableID) 
FROM DiningTable
WHERE IsAvail = 1;
```

I can get the "Number of Table" logically, however I want to use that number in the next sql query.

```
UPDATE DiningTable
SET IsAvail = 0
WHERE TableID = 11 - [Should be the number of Table, the result I get above];
```

What can I do?

Comment: Looks weird. How can the TableID (which looks like a primary key) be equal to the number of tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE DiningTable
SET IsAvail = 0
WHEN TableID = 11 - (SELECT COUNT(TableID) FROM DiningTable WHERE IsAvail = 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

make sure to put the isnull() check to avoid a null error if the first select return 0 rows

```
UPDATE DiningTable
SET IsAvail = 0
WHEN TableID = 11 - (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(TableID),0) FROM DiningTable WHERE IsAvail = 1);
```